# Should cellForRowAt gets called only for visible cells after tableview.reloadData at the beginning?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I called the `tableView.reloadData` from `viewDidLoad`, the `cellForRowAt` gets called for rows that are not visible at the beginning. For example,  10 `cellForRowAt` gets called while each cell has a row height approximately the screen height with autolayout constraint. But shouldn't the `cellForRowAt` those rows at the very bottom called at the beginning since they are not yet visible?

Comment: How are you setting the heights of the rows?

Comment: With autolayout  UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: Your comment actually help me think of changing the estimatedRowHeight to a bigger value, so that only the first two cellForRowAt  gets called

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I need to set the initial estimate row height for the tableView to a bigger value, something like

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 400
```

Then only the `cellForRowAt` for the first two rows gets called